# GCP Background Function and pub/sub configurable retry is not configurable (terrible decision), what are the alternatives?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Since configurable retry does not work between CloudFunction and Pub/Sub how do you guys usually manage your retry ? Could not find any way to delay the retry. Really seems like a terrible limitation of GCP Cloud Function [...]

Comment: Use HTTP functions, or Cloud Run, and a PubSub push subscription to have more controle on the PubSub subscription (filter, dead letter topics, retries,....)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean that configurable re-tries doesn't work between Cloud Function and pubsub? [This guide shows how to configure re-tries safely between pubsub and cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#enabling_and_disabling_retries).

Comment: It is not configurable @JakeNelson ... Meaning your are losing the power of pub/sub

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere will try directly using push.

Comment: You can enable retries, but not customize them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use configurable retry on a subscription with Cloud Functions, then set up an [HTTP-based trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) and use the trigger URL as the push endpoint in a subscription you create separately. When you create that subscription, you can enable the retry policy or any other properties not exposed in subscriptions created directly via Cloud Functions.